How to connect a Battery Charging board / Management system, directly to a phones PCB to provide an alternative port for charging?
I have a Welcome phone (a no name phone) where I'm hoping to use the standard phone charging port for other uses. So I thought that I could solider a Battery Management system   (BMS) directly to the PCB, I believe the BMS I have should suit the phones specs, although it's not an exact match, but close.
My first Attempt:
Where the Battery currently connects to the PCB there are two large terminals either side of the connection, I tried soldiering the BMS directly to these but this gave no noticeable result, although possibly this may have been sending charge directly to the battery, however I did not leave this connected long enough to check it was charging. With this configuration the phone would not turn on without the battery connected.
My second Attempt:
Above where the battery connects, there are 3 terminals. I tried connecting the BMS to the positive and negative. With out the battery connected, this allowed the phone to turn on, but then the phone would quickly turn off again. I wondered if the third, middle terminal was perhaps for a temperature sensor, so I tried to satisfy this by adding a 10k resistor from this middle terminal to the positive. (you can see the resistor soldiered to the middle terminal at the moment, and the other side close to the positive but not connected) This made no noticeable difference.
Phone Specs: (as written on the battery)
Standard Voltage (what it runs on I assume): 3.85v, 17.9Wh
Charge Voltage Limit: 4.4v

BMS Specs:
Charge: 3.7v
Charging current: 3A
Charge cut off Voltage: 4.35v

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and if this is possible. Ideally I'd like to be able to connect a power supply to the BMS and for the phone to register in the OS that it's being charged.
Thing's I could try:
Disassembling the battery, and directly connecting to the Battery's BMS.
Looking further in to the PCB where the original port is connected and soldering on to it. At the moment I can not visibly see any clear terminals there. However I feel this is not viable as it will effect the way the port functions.

I should also say, the port type of the phone is USB-c but the specification is USB-2, thus there is no pin 4 equivalent in terms of micro B to allow OTG.
What else could I try?



Usually the battery's thermistor is connected to ground (-) terminal. Did you try this? Also, it could be not a thermistor but some serial communication/identification pin, and the phone expects some response form it.

yes, I believe your right. In the above photo I was trying to place the resistor between the positive and middle terminal (BSI / BTemp), this was a mistake, I later changed to the negitive terminal and the middle terminal (BSI/BTemp). This didn't make any difference.
I found when trying to read the resistance between the BSI pin and GND with a multimedia I couldn't read it, but if I read the voltage I got 0.3v.   Which I take as being about 1k resistance, so I tried a 1k resistor as well with no luck.

An update, I tried adding a diode to prevent the battery from discharging through the external power source.
I wasn't measuring the resistance correctly before, but tried a number of different resistance options and didn't have any luck. - Going to leave this project for now

Other things I tried, connecting to the Battery's BMS board and soldering on to it, using an Amp reader on the USB cable I could see the battery and phone was taking a charge, but the phone didn't register the charge so it never moved towards the full range.
I also tried soldering directly on to the back of the PCB where the phones port was, this allowed the phone to charge correctly. But if I connected anything to the USB port it would function but kill the charging.
I hoped this would be much simpler
